# Installing NPM on Ubuntu 14.0 giving python 2.7 dependency issue

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, npm-install

I am installing npm on the ubuntu 14.0. It is already having installed python 2.7.11. It is showing the following error.

```
Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     apt-xapian-index : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     duplicity : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     gconf2 : Depends: python:any
     hplip-data : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     ibus : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     ibus-pinyin : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     ibus-table : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     landscape-client-ui-install : Depends: python:any
     npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-ansi but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-nopt (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
     python-apt : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-aptdaemon : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-cairo : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-chardet : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-commandnotfound : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-crypto : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
     python-cupshelpers : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-dbus : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-debian : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-debtagshw : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-defer : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-dirspec : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-gi : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-gobject-2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-gtk2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-httplib2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-ibus : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-imaging : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-libxml2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-lockfile : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-lxml : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-notify : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-oauthlib : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                       Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
     python-oneconf : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-openssl : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-pexpect : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-pil : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-piston-mini-client : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-pkg-resources : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7)
                            Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
     python-qt4 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-reportlab : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-requests : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                       Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
     python-samba : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-serial : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-sip : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-six : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                  Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
     python-smbc : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-twisted-core : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-twisted-web : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-ubuntu-sso-client : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-urllib3 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                      Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
     python-xapian : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-xdg : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-zeitgeist : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     python-zope.interface : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     sessioninstaller : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     software-center : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     software-center-aptdaemon-plugins : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     totem : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     totem-plugins : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     ubuntu-sso-client-qt : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     ubuntu-system-service : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     unity : Depends: python:any
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: this problem still exist on Ubutnu 20.04, 6 years later, except that this time it depends on python2.7-minimal

Answer (score 0):

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages
```

You try what it told you to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this first:

`apt-get update`

and then

`apt-get -f install`.

If that doesn't work try **aptitude**  package manager. It gives multiple solutions and you can select one.